# apache spark pivot dynamically

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

The pivot clause is available in Apache Spark SQL. However, it expects an expression_list which works when you know in advance what columns you expect. However, I would like to pivot on columns dynamically.

In my use case, I would need to retrieve the data to list in a query and then pass that into IN.

I just don't see how I can do this, beyond dynamically building the SQL string and applying the expression_list as a parameter, like building a template to then execute the query.

This would be fine, if I was able to do this in a Databricks notebook(in my case), however, I'm writing a query in Databricks SQL, which only accepts SQL, I have no ability to build an SQL string.

Would really appreciate any advice and how to resolve this issue.

```
%sql
drop table person;
CREATE TABLE person (id INT, name STRING, age INT, class INT, address STRING);
INSERT INTO person VALUES
    (100, 'John', 30, 1, 'Street 1'),
    (200, 'Mary', NULL, 1, 'Street 2'),
    (300, 'Mike', 80, 3, 'Street 3'),
    (400, 'Dan', 50, 4, 'Street 4');

SELECT * FROM person
    PIVOT (
        SUM(age) AS a
        FOR name IN ('John', 'Dan')
    )
```